# Firebase Database suddenly stops working on few android devices

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using below code for connecting to `Firebase` database.

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("email", "Password")
        .addOnCompleteListener(this,
                new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Overridepublic
                    void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        } else {
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Its working fine for few days and its suddenly has stopped working. If i clear the app cache and reopen the app its start working. Please anyone help me solution for this issue.

Comment: can you provide the logcat about this issue?

Comment: In production its happening i cant able to take log. Even its not throwing any error in crashlytics also

Comment: Try to get the log and add it here to see what is happening.

Comment: Hi @Alex in which case firebase token will refresh. I read in some blogs that token will refreshed in firebase but in app if it's old token then it will cause the issue. In my case I am using email and password authentication and it works fine for first time installation but after few days it's suddenly stops working. If we clear the cache and reopen the app then it's start working . I can't able to find root cause for this issue. In debug this case not recreated so I can't able to collect the logs